# How do I activate an inputView using a UIButton in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, inputview

I am attempting to have a UIDatePicker come up as a keyboard when the user hits a UIButton. I was able to get it to work with a textfield, but I don't like how the cursor is visible and the user could enter in any text if they had an external keyboard. Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func dateFieldStart(sender: UITextField) {
        var datePickerStartView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerStartView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
        sender.inputView = datePickerStartView    // error when sender is UIButton
}
```

I tried changing the sender to UIButton but it gave this error on the line that is marked above:

```
Cannot assign to 'inputView' in 'sender'
```

I have tried researching it and no one else seems to have had a problem with it. Anyone know how to trigger a UIDatePicker inputView using a UIButton or anything that might work better that the user cannot type into? Thanks!

Comment: UIButton doesn't have an inputView property. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want a button to trigger a popup UIDatePicker so I can get a date variable without cluttering the UI.

Comment: You can create a view for the picker off screen view and move it on screen when you need it.

Comment: That is definitely an option, but I would really love to use inputView or something like it if I can.

Comment: InputView is a better option. I had the popup method before, but uitableView will not auto adjust when it appears.

Answer (score 12):

This is years after the original question, but for anyone who may be looking for solution to this you can subclass UIButton and provide a getter and setter for the inputView property. Be sure to call becomeFirstResponder in the setter and override canBecomeFirstResponder. For example:

```
class MyButton: UIButton {

    var myView: UIView? = UIView()
    var toolBarView: UIView? = UIView()
    
    override var inputView: UIView? {
        get {
            myView
        }
        
        set {
            myView = newValue
            becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        get {
            toolBarView
        }
        set {
            toolBarView = newValue
        }
    }
    
    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
       true
    }

}
```

Comment: How to use this in code? I tried this "myButton.inputView = myPicker"

Comment: I added a tap gesture recogniser to the button instance. When the button is tapped I set the delegate for the picker. Then set a `myButton.inputAccessoryView` to a `UIToolbar` and `myButton.InputView = myPicker`. If you want to set a few attributes for the toolbar maybe create a separate function which will return a `UIToolbar`.

Answer (score 4):

```
let tempInput = UITextField( frame:CGRect.zero )
tempInput.inputView = self.myPickerView       // Your picker
self.view.addSubview( tempInput )
tempInput.becomeFirstResponder()
```

It's a good idea to keep a reference to `tempInput` so you can clean-up on close

Comment: The whole point of op's question is that he does not want to use a `UITextField()` inputView, and don't know how to use the inputView property of a UIButton because it is `get-only` so this answer feels a little bit off-topic. Thank for participating anyway 

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do the same thing, I ended up just overlaying a UITextField over the button and using the inputView of that instead.

Tip: set `tintColor` of the UITextField to `UIColor.clearColor()` to hide the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view for the picker off screen view and move it on screen when you need it. Here's [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28630417/613858) post on this.